# What does colon mean in Python string formatting?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am learning the Python string `format()` method. Though I understand that `{}` is a placeholder for arguments, I am not sure what `:` represent in the following code snippet from [Programiz tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format):

```
import datetime
# datetime formatting
date = datetime.datetime.now()
print("It's now: {:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}".format(date))



# custom __format__() method
class Person:
    def __format__(self, format):
        if(format == 'age'):
            return '23'
        return 'None'

print("Adam's age is: {:age}".format(Person()))
```

1. Why is there a `:` in front of `%Y` in `print("It's now: {:%Y/%m/%d...`? The code outputs `It's now: 2021`, and there is no `:` in front of 2021.
2. Why is there a `:` in front of `age` in  `print("Adam's age is: {:age}...`?

Thanks in advance for your valuable input!!

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. my underestanding is the `:` in front of an argument calls the `__format__` method of the object that you pass in to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python objects decide for themselves how they should be formatted using the `__format__` method. Mostly we just use the defaults that come with the basic types, but much like `__str__` and `__repr__` we can customize. The stuff after the colon `:` is the parameter to `__format__`.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...             print(repr(spec))
...             return "I will stubbornly refuse your format"
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print("Its now {:myformat}".format(f))
'myformat'
Its now I will stubbornly refuse your format
```

we can call the formatter ourselves. `datetime` uses the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) format rules.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> # datetime formatting
>>> date = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print("It's now: {:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}".format(date))
It's now: 2021/10/04 11:12:23
>>> date.__format__(":%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
':2021/10/04 11:12:23'
```

Your custom `Person` class implemented `__format__` and used the format specifier after the colon to return a value.

Answer (score 2):

Everything after `:` is a parameter to the `__format__()` method of the class of the corresponding arguent. For instance, for a number you can write `{:.2f}` to format it as a decimal number with 2 digits of precision after the decimal point.

For a `datetime` value, it's a format string that could be used with `datetime.strftime()`.

And in your `Person` class, it will be passed as the `format` argument to `Person.__format__()`. So if you don't put `:age` there, the `if` condition will fail and it will print `None` instead of `23`.

Answer (score 0):

Try f-strings. In them the colon seems to be more reasonable. It delimits the variable name and its formatting options:

```
import datetime

# datetime formatting

date = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f"It's now: {date:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}")

# custom __format__() method

class Person:
    def __format__(self, format):
        if(format == 'age'):
            return '23'
        return 'None'

print(f"Adam's age is: {Person():age}")
```

Btw you can have similar functionality with keyword arguments to `format()`:

```
print("It's now: {d:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}".format(d=date))

print("Adam's age is: {adam:age}".format(adam=Person()))
```

Comment: This is really cool! I tried with f-strings actually but i didn't know it supported format method. The `:age` part is I think what I was missing.

Comment: Names work with .format also - its the name of the format keyword argument.`print("It's now: {mydate:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}".format(mydate=date))`

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you for your comment, but it's not that I didn't mention it in my answer.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins - names have been a part of .format since its creation. Its not a forward compatibility thing. There is a big difference. With f-strings, its a name in the containing namespace. With .format, its a keyword argument name.

Comment: @tdelaney `.format` itself is a forward compatibility thing in respect to f-strings.